# Get the slug from navigation element in Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been looking and trying different things now for about three days with no success; I've asked on other forums and tried searching on Google, Bing and Yahoo and could not find the answer, and I've looked in WordPress.org and still nothing.

Could someone please put me out of my misery and point to how I may achieve this?

Basically at the moment my code looks like this:

```
$newlink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $item->title));

        if($item->description == 'blog'){

            $attributes  = ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->title ) .'"';
            $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( '#content' ) .'"';

        } elseif($item->description == 'home'){

            $attributes  = ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->title ) .'"';
            $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( site_url() ) .'"';

        } elseif($item->description == 'linkout'){

            $attributes  = ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->title ) .'"';
            $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"';

        } else {

            $attributes  = ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->title ) .'"';
            $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( site_url() . '/#' . $newlink) .'"';

        }
```

But as you may guess this code becomes bad when using languages which use special chars. This is because I am using `$item->title`.

How do I get the slug which is automatically created and sanitised to account for the special chars? - I thought it would be as simple as `$item->slug` but it is not :(

Comment: did you try with post_name?

Comment: @patrick sorry about the late reply :( Yes I tried this, it just gave an id for some reason.

Comment: this is because wordpress creates another post (with type nav_menu_item) for each menu item, so you get the wrong slug (that's the id of the menu item). Not sure if there's an easy way to get the slug of the original post.